# demo code provided by overleaf causes error on overleaf

Tags: overleaf

[overleaf doc](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Chinese#xeCJK_with_XeLaTeX) gives this demo to illustrate the usage of xeCJK

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}

\section{前言}

\section{关于数学部分}
数学、中英文皆可以混排。You can intersperse math, Chinese and English (Latin script) without adding extra environments.

這是繁體中文。
\end{document}
```

run the code above on overleaf causes 28 errors.

here is the first one

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty, line 43
Critical Package xeCJK Error: The xeCJK package requires XeTeX to function.

(xeCJK)                         
(xeCJK)                         You must change your typesetting engine to
(xeCJK)                         "xelatex"
(xeCJK)                         instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex" or
(xeCJK)                         "lualatex".
(xeCJK)                         Loading xeCJK will abort!

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.43 ..._critical:nn { xeCJK } { Require-XeTeX } }
```

it seems that I need to change the typesetting engine. How to change the typesetting engine overleaf?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link to instructions](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler) for changing backend compiler according to Overleaf's website.

It suggests going to `Menu --> Settings --> Compiler` and select the appropriate one.